# Создать узлы по XPath

Tags: c#, xml

Подскажите, а есть ли в C# штатный способ по XPath создать всю ветку узлов?

Скажем, на вход я подаю XPath root/node1/node2/node3 и мне будет создана вся это ветка в XDocument.

Или можно только ручками итеративно создавать XElement'ы друг за другом?

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [Create XML Nodes based on XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/508390/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 Получается, что только ручками=(

Comment: ну я другого метода не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    string XPath = "root/node1/node2/node3";
    string[] root = { XPath.Split('/').First() };

    XElement xmlTree = new XElement (XPath.Split('/').First());

    foreach (string st in XPath.Split('/').Except(root))
    {
        xmlTree.Add(new XElement(st, "some value"));
    }
}
```

**Результат**

```
<root>
  <node1>some value</node1>
  <node2>some value</node2>
  <node3>some value</node3>
</root>
```

**Или**

```
void Main()
{
    string XPath = "root/node1/node2/node3";
    string[] root = { XPath.Split('/').First() };

    XElement xmlTree = new XElement(XPath.Split('/').First());

    foreach (string st in XPath.Split('/').Except(root))
    {
        xmlTree.DescendantsAndSelf().Last().Add(new XElement(st));
    }
    xmlTree.Dump();
}
```

**Результат**

```
<root>
  <node1>
    <node2>
      <node3 />
    </node2>
  </node1>
</root>
```

Comment: `root/node1/node2/node3` это подразумевает, что узлы вложенные друг в друга, а у вас они радом сидят в одном контейнере.

Comment: Исправлено. Сейчас две версии.

Comment: второй рабочий, но много лишниз операций. Такое, что вы делаете, можно сделать в одну строку и оптимальней с точки зрения производительности `"root/node1/node2/node3".Split('/').Select(x=>new XElement(x)).Reverse().Aggregate((x, y) => { y.Add(x); return y;}).Dump();`

Comment: Artem, Очень круто